# C# handle instance of an object after continue in foreach loop

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Let's assume I have an instance of this class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string LocationCode;
    public string PickUpCode
}
```

There is another class that takes a `List<MyClass>` as input and saves to the DB.

Now I need to apply some business rules:

For example if **LocationCode** is `null` this item in the `List<MyClass>` must be skipped and the `foreach` loop must `continue` to the next item in the list.

I've written the following code and the items with `null` **LocationCode** are indeed skipped but the `var instance = new SomeClass();` somehow remains in memory so when the loop reaches an valid item and proceeds to save it in the DB, it also saves all the previously skipped instances of `var instance = new SomeClass();`. Which means I have null entries in the DB.

I'm using **NHibernate** and `Evict`doesn't seam to be doing the trick. Any suggestions?

```
public void Save(List<MyClass> listOfItems)
{
    using (UnitOfWork.Start())
    {
        var repository = new Repository();

        try
        {

            foreach (var item in listOfItems.Select(i => i.Item).Where(item => item != null))
            {
                var instance = new SomeClass();         

                if (pickUpCode != null)
                {
                    instance.PickUpCode = pickUpCode;
                }
                else
                {               
                    instance.PickUpCode = null;
                }

                if (locationCode != null)
                {
                    instance.StartLocation = locationCode
                }
                else
                {
                    UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.Evict(instance);
                    continue;
                }

                repository.SaveSomeClass(instance);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(" Unhandled error", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

** Because someone asked, here's some code on `UnitOfWork.Start()`

```
public static class UnitOfWork
    {        
        public static IUnitOfWork Start();
    }

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        bool IsInActiveTransaction { get; }
        IUnitOfWorkFactory SessionFactory { get; }

        IGenericTransaction BeginTransaction();
        IGenericTransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
        void Flush();
        void TransactionalFlush();
        void TransactionalFlush(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't you miss `if(item.pickUpCode != null)` and `if(item.locationCode != null)` ?

Comment: this is a sample code. The actual one is far more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you fail first and avoid all of this?

Example being:

```
foreach (var item in listOfItems.Select(i => i.Item).Where(item => item != null))
        {

            if (item.LocationCode == null){
              continue;
            }

            var instance = new SomeClass();         

            if (pickUpCode != null)
            {
                instance.PickUpCode = pickUpCode;
            }
            else
            {               
                instance.PickUpCode = null;
            }

            // if we reach here, location code is definitley not null, no need for the check            
            instance.StartLocation = locationCode



            repository.SaveSomeClass(instance);
        }
```

Alternatively, you could add the check to you LINQ where clause

```
foreach (var item in listOfItems.where(item=> item != null && item.LocationCode != null)
```

Comment: Combination of that and a `UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.Clear();` command did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Without more code on how UnitofWork.Start works its hard to suggest. But, It's worth trying by implementing IDisposable on SomeClass.

Comment: I thought of that too.

Comment: sorry deviating from your comment. michael moore suggestion is right but again you won't be able compile. Any way, yes c# GC is good doing that.  My hunch is UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.Evict(instance); this code, don't know what happening this blackbox where it may still hold the reference of the instance.